# Local(Block) function decln vs. defn return type mismatch; Diagnostic in C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

This program is in the file called localFunc.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// int f(int);  // Global forward declaration.

int main() {
   int f(int);  // Local forward declaration.
   printf("%d\n", f(1));
}

double f(int i) {
   return 1.0;
}
```

Compiling via `gcc localFunc.c` gives:

```
localFunc.c:10:8: error: conflicting types for ‘f’
 double f(int i) {
        ^
localFunc.c:6:7: note: previous declaration of ‘f’ was here
    int f(int);  // Local forward declaration.
```

But compiled via `g++ localFunc.c`, there is no error and the result of running the executable is: `4195638`.

Commenting out the Local forward declaration, and turning on the Global forward declaration of: `int f(int);`, both gcc and g++ give errors similar to the above, as expected(by me).

So my question is, why does it appear that g++ is not seeing the conflicting types(ambiguous declaration) on locally declared functions?

```
don@HAL:~/UNIX/CS213$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
```

Comment: Is not it like C and C++ are different languages?

Comment: @Leushenko But you can't overload based on return type only. Also, g++ might compile the code as C due to the file name. Either way, it shouldn't compile.

Comment: If you want to use printf, make sure you pass the correct format string. In this case, I'm guessing that the global overload is used, so `%lf` should be used instead of `%d`. However I would recommend `std::cout << f(1)<< std::endl;`
Note that gcc does notice this inconsistency and tells you it'll have problems with it and most likely a reinterpret_cast will occur for 1.0 to an int

Comment: @juanchopanza: The code is wrong, but is a diagnostic actually mandated in this case?

Comment: What is the problem? Ruby behaves different that Rust, C than C++, Java different than Pascal, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can explain this behavior for C++.

From the C++11 spec, section 3.5 [basic.link], paragraph (7):

> When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found to refer to some other declaration, then that entity is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. However such a declaration does not introduce the member name in its namespace scope.

So the `int f(int)` declaration has global linkage, but does not introduce the name into the global namespace. This might explain why GCC does not notice the conflict.

More importantly, paragraph (10) says:

> After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs (7.1.3) are replaced by their definitions), the types specified by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical, except that declarations for an array object can specify array types that differ by the presence or absence of a major array bound (8.3.4). A violation of this rule on type identity does not require a diagnostic.

Your program violates the "shall" portion of this paragraph, so its behavior is undefined. That means anything GCC does whatsoever -- such as calling the `double foo(int)` function and treating its return value as an int -- is permitted by the spec. Moreover, no diagnostic is required.

I do not know what C says about this case; in particular, whether the diagnostic is required.

Comment: Thank you, that does seem to explain what is happening here. So one should be careful to self-check that the function type of a function declared within a block matches that function's definition, as the compiler may not.

Comment: @user1666237: Yes. Also, this sort of local declaration for a global name is, in my experience, very unusual... In fact I have never seen one in production code. The usual approach is to put *all* non-static declarations into header files and `#include` them as appropriate. That way, the compiler will tell you about this sort of mismatch even across translation units.

Comment: Agreed  (comment to >15 chars)